# Memory leaks after using clear in an std::unordered_map C++

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am working in a large project and have run into some trouble.

Essentially, I have a class called `DataSet`. This `DataSet` class uses an `std::unordered_map` called `objects` as the data structure. It looks sort of like this:

```
// DataSet.h
#include "Object.h"
#include <unordered_map>

// Assume I have set up my hash key and all relevant header things
class Object;

class DataSet{
    public:
        std::unordered_map<int, Object*, DataSetHashKey> objects;

        int enum_type;

        DataSet();
        ~DataSet();
        DataSet *Copy(void);
        int AddObject(int key, Object* obj);
        // I have various functions (like delete object, size, clear) here
}

// DataSet.cpp
#include "DataSet.h"
#include "Object.h"

DataSet::DataSet(){
    objects.max_load_factor(0.75);
}

DataSet::~DataSet(){
    objects.clear();
}

DataSet* DataSet::Copy(void){
    DataSet* copy = this;
    return copy;
}

int DataSet::AddObject(int key, Object* obj){
    objects[key] = obj;
    return 1;
}
```

The key for the `unordered_map` in this case is an enum for a specific type of (unique) `Object`, and `Object` itself is a virtual class. Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the way `Object` handles pointers. The program must use a pointer to an `Object` as the value.

Here is the `Object` class:

```
/* Object.h */
class Object{
    public:
        virtual ~Object(){};
        virtual int ObjectEnum()=0;
        virtual Object* copy()=0;
}
```

Something that might use this class would be a `Parameter` such as a `BooleanParameter`. Here is that class definition (assuming we set up a header file for it already and we have a member for the class: `int enum_t` and `bool val`):

```
/* BooleanParameter.cpp */
#include "Object.h"
BooleanParameter::BooleanParameter(int enum_type, bool value) {
    enum_t = enum_type;
    val = value;
}

BooleanParameter::~BooleanParameter(){
    return;
}

Object* BooleanParameter::copy() {
    return new BooleanParameter(this->enum_t, this->val);
}
```

And finally this is used in a class called `Parameters` which will set this boolean value with this function:

```
void Parameters::SetParameter(bool boolean, int enum_type) {
    this->DataSet::AddObject(enum_type, new BoolParam(enum_type,boolean));
}
```

Hopefully I've given enough information to determine why I might be getting memory leaks now. So before, I could have sworn I tested this implementation and after running valgrind, came up clean (with no memory leaks). However, I was trying to speed some things up on an unrelated file and after running valgrind, I started to get these errors:

```
==39126== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 30 of 277
==39126==    at 0x47E1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==39126==    by 0x1B3A28D: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==39126==    by 0x17752D: Parameters::SetParameter(bool, int) (Parameters.cpp:245)
==39126==    by 0x100000F62: main (main.cpp:16)
========================
==39126== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 31 of 277
==39126==    at 0x47E1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==39126==    by 0x1B3A28D: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==39126==    by 0x17E752: BooleanParameter::copy() (BooleanParameter.cpp:53)
==39126==    by 0x100000F62: main (main.cpp:16)
```

Only this error happens probably hundreds of times. I reverted to my old copy which I thought had previously passed. Unfortunately now however, it appears to be still giving me the same memory leak error. So I'm assuming I forgot and it didn't actually pass.

Anyways, I have a feeling this has to do with the way I'm using `new` in `BooleanParameter::Copy(void)` and within `Parameters::SetParameter`. Or since it's saying the memory that was created was not destroyed, does it have to do with my `std::unordered_map<...>` destructor which just calls clear on the `DataSet`?

I've been messing around trying to find the cause of this issue but I can't really figure it out and don't want to break more things :(

Edit: What I'm trying to ask for right now at least is:

If I did stick with raw pointers, where do I free the memory? In the destructor of the `unordered_map`? In the destructor of the `Parameters` class? Or in the destructor of `BooleanParameter` itself? And since I am returning so many new instances of a class, what do I even call `delete` on?

Comment: If you allocate memory with `new` you must free it with `delete`. [`std::map::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear) just removes all entries from the map, it doesn't "free" anything you have allocated.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm now realizing that after reading clear a bit more. I'm wondering though. how could I free everything while still doing things like `return new BooleanParameter(...)` or `AddObject(key, new BooleanParameter(...))`? Or is there another way I should be calling `copy` and `AddObject`

Comment: @Alex Think about this.  A container that holds pointers has no idea that you called `new`, `new[]`, `malloc`, `calloc`, or some other memory allocation function, or no memory allocation function (you could have just placed any address there).  Given that, how would a container know which deallocation function to call (or none at all)?  It doesn't.  That is your responsibility to deallocate the memory.

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr<Object>` in the hash map if you want this class to take ownership of the memory and free it when `clear` is called.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Unfortunately I don't know if I can implement that because there are hundreds of classes that inherit from `Object`, and hundreds of subclasses inheriting from those classes which all use raw pointers.

Comment: @Alex You may be surprised.  My experience is that it does not take a relatively long time to convert "hundreds" of classes to smart pointers, or arrays to vectors, or some other transformation.  Change the declaration, fix the compiler errors, test.  A day, day and a half, at most. (again, my experience).

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but if you want to understand and use c++ correctly, then RUN from this big project if you can. This is not c++ it's Java in disguise.

Comment: @Alex Why does it matter if hundreds of class inherit from `Object`? What does that have to do with using `std::unique_ptr` in the `DataSet` class? `Object* foo = new /* derived type goes here*/; delete foo;` works correctly doesn't it?

Comment: @Alex In any event, you have to write your code to do `delete` correctly, (no double-frees and things like that).  That alone could make the code hard to debug if you're stuck with not using smart pointers.  So make your choice -- more code that could have bugs that are close to, if not near impossible to figure out when and where to deallocate, or use smart pointers and not worry about those things.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll look into implementing `unique_ptr` then. I have a feeling though that some of these sub classes that will use `Object` through another inherited classes are not unique. So it may not apply then. At least that was the case when I tried to implement it before. I gave up the first time and stuck with the original code because of this issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm also trying to understand. If I did stick with raw pointers, where do I free the memory? In the destructor of the unordered_map? In the destructor of the `Parameters` class? Or in the destructor of `BooleanParameter` itself? And since I am returning so many `new` instances of a class, what do I even call `delete` on?

Comment: @Alex If there is no coherency in who owns what pointer and if it's a design that is basicaly "I don't care who owns the pointer, the last person holding it is responsible for deletion", then you can use `std::shared_ptr<Object>`.  But beware of the caveats of `std::shared_ptr` (no cycles, for example).